# usar o token csrf gerado automaticamente pelo laravel sem usar o blade

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Estou desenvolvendo um App com Cordova e queria saber se é possível utilizar o token `csrf` gerado pelo Laravel, sem ter que configurar a tag meta utilizando Blade, como é ensinado no site do laravel:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Pois obviamente não é possível utilizar o Blade nem PHP no Cordova para gerar as telas somente HTML, CSS e Javascript.

Comment: você não consegue algo do tipo <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

Comment: Não, pois as telas do meu app são html, porém utilizo o php  no lado do servidor

Comment: suas telas são em .html?

Comment: Sim , exato....

Comment: Se você está usando o Cordova, provavelmente você vai fazer a requisição de forma externa. Eu entendo que `csrf_token` é pra evitar requisições forjadas. Eu desativaria a verificação csrf_token na parte da API que fará a comunicação com o Cordova, e faria outra forma de segurança/autenticação.

Comment: bacana , na verdade eu ja desativei, ja imaginava que teria que fazer isso , valeu obrigado